# dynamically viewing edittext from spinners

Tags: java, if-statement, android-studio, android-edittext, spinner

I have an app that has a spinner (spinner5) which, when the "Other" tab is selected, will show a series of editext. However, when I select the tab, the EditText do not appear. Any help is appreciated.

```
     a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText34);
    a.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText35);
    b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText36);
    c.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    if (spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Other")) {
        a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

The following is my strings.xml

```
     <string-array name="site_location">
    <item>ETAK NC</item>
    <item>ETAK OH</item>
    <item>ETAK IL</item>
    <item>ETAK GA</item>
    <item>ETAK TX</item>
    <item>ETAK CA</item>
    <item>Left on site (CA)</item>
    <item> Other</item>
    <item>Transferring to other site</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it right after i posted this lol. Rookie mistake, I realized that I didn' t have the `if`  statement in the `onItemSelected()` method.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Other")) {
        a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```